# Sending alert from the client side based on the response from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I'm using `express.js` as server-side and plain JavaScript as the client-side. In the sign-up route, I want to add the user only if he/she hasn't already signed up. If already signed up, I want to have an alert message 'User already signed-up'. Between the submit button of the form in the sign-up route redirects to the `/users/add` route . Here's the `/users/add` route...

```js
app.post('/users/add', (req, res, next) => {
  user = {
    name: req.body.name,
    studentID: req.body.studentID,
    password: req.body.password
  }
  let count = 0;
  Users.find({}).toArray((err, users) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      if (users[i].studentID == user.studentID)
        count++;
    }
    // Add user if not already signed up
    if (count == 0) {
      Users.insert(user, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('User added...');
        res.redirect('/');
      });
    } else {
      // Alert message logic here
    }
  });
```

How can I achieve this using plain JavaScript?
Thanks...

Comment: Instead of redirecting to `/`, render the index view and pass along an error parameter. In your view, check for the error and display it.

Comment: You need something like this: `res.render('login', { error: "user already exists" });` Also, using plain JavaScript doesn't preclude you from sending the form using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Just send a message back to the client like "user exists". When the client receives it, `alert("The user already exists").`

```
if(users.length){
    res.status(409).send("user exists")
}
```

And in your front-end, whatever framework you use :

```
if(response=="user exists") alert("The user already exists")
```

BTW you don't need the `count` variable. You're only counting `users.length`. Use `users.length` directly.

Also, there's a flaw in this bit of code :

```
if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
}
```

You're exiting the function without replying to the client, therefore your HTTP call will hang forever and will result in a timeout. You must always reply to the client :

```
if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).send(err);
}
```

Comment: This assumes the form is sent using AJAX, but I suspect it isn't.

Comment: What do you call a Nodejs route with, if not Ajax? It's clearly a POST request to the `/users/add` route

Comment: It is, as made when `<form action="/users/add" method="post">` is submitted. The backend language doesn't matter, using node.js doesn't mean the client is a SPA.

Comment: Ah, that's problematic then. We need to write an `.onsubmit()` handler. I'm far too used to Angular's `http` calls.

Comment: It's not at all a problem in angular . Works fine . But using plain javascript makes it tricky

Comment: I still couldn't solve this issue. When i try to do res.status(409).send("user exists") the server opens up a new page with the text user exists written on it. How to send the JSON response from the express server and then fetch it in the client side( here client side is just plain javascript and not any frameworks like angular)?

Comment: It's because this is not an ajax call. If it was, your page wouldn't change, and you would just get this from the server in the callback. You need to override the default `form.onsubmit` function and [write your own](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_submit.asp), I guess